# Where did the 22NM come from in acceptable VOR signal on a MOCA? Why 22NM?

Tags: navigation

SO a MOCA provides ROC along entire route but acceptable VOR nav signal for only 22NM.  Why 22NM?

Comment: Just a comment: 22NM is just a little above 40km. Maybe someone used 40km, converted to nautical miles, and then rounded to the higher number.

Comment: Shielding by terrain?

Comment: Looks suspiciously like 25 statute miles to me, which would be a very typical distance increment back when VORs were first deployed (by 1946, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHF_omnidirectional_range).